# How to overwrite `savefig` method so that it can unpack a tuple

Tags: python, savefig

I am working on a minimal extension to a piece of code.

I have a `make_fig` function that used to produce just one figure, which I would call as `fig` in the lots of other fuctions then save it as `fig.savefig`.

In the extension, `make_fig` now returns a *tuple* of figures. So, to save them all, I would now need need something like:

```
fig = make_fig

for f in fig:
   f.savefig
```

I was hoping for a more elegant solution, one that does not require a for loop to be added anywhere `make_fig` appears.

Can I somehow modify the `a.savefig` method so that it does its normal function if `a` is a `matplotlib.pytplot` instance, and does the for loop thing above if it's a tuple?

MWE below.

`d = 1` is the "old" code, `d=2` is the extension I want to add.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def make_fig(d):
    if d==1:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    elif d==2:
        fig1, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        fig2, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        fig = (fig1, fig2)
    else:
        raise Exception('error')
    return fig

d=2
fig = make_fig(d)
fig.savefig('hello.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implement your own `savefig` function that can handle both cases.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def savefig(filename, fig):
    if not isinstance(fig, Iterable):
        fig = (fig,)
    for i, f in enumerate(fig):
        f.savefig(f'{filename}_{i}.jpg')


fig = make_fig(1)
savefig('test1', fig)
fig = make_fig(2)
savefig('test2', fig)
```

After execution, we have `test1_0.jpg`, `test2_0.jpg` and `test2_1.jpg`.

As an alternative to the `if` check, you can use the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) approach:

```
def savefig(filename, fig):
    try:
        fig.savefig(filename)
    except AttributeError:
        for i, f in enumerate(fig):
            f.savefig(f'{filename}_{i}.jpg')
```

Comment: thanks. inside your `custom_savefig`, how would I refer to `fig`?

Comment: @SuperCiocia with `self`, I updated my answer

Comment: But this only works if `fig` is a Figure, so that it has `savefig` as a method. What if my `fig = (fig1, fig2)`, where `fig1` and `fig2` are Figures?

Comment: @SuperCiocia See updated answer, a simpler and much safer solution

Comment: @SuperCiocia `from collections.abc import Iterable`

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace, I think this issue almost similar to another issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/68348996/6446053 . Appreciate if you can drop by and share some insight

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, rather than returning a tuple, you can return your own object, which has the tuple as one of the fields.

```
class MultipleFigures:

    def __init__(self, figures):
        self.figures = figures

    def savefig(self):
        for fig in self.figures:
            fig.savefig()
```

The `make fig` function can then return either a `matplotlib.pytplot` instance or a `MultipleFigures` instance.